# how to set an onclick listener for an imagebutton in an alertdialog

Tags: android, onclick, android-alertdialog, imagebutton

I have a layout with an ImageButton that is inflated in an AlertDialog, where/how should I set an onClick listener?

Here's the code I tried using:

```
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TravelBite.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong, I needed to find the ImageButton from the inflated view first.

Answer (score 29):

Try to put like this in ur code

e.g:-if your alertdialog's object is ad,then

```
 ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) ad.findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TravelBite.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above proved useful but I used "this" (not "ad") for the context:

```
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TravelBite.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

This is easier for copying and pasting ;-)

Thanks for the previous code I woulnd have found the solution above without it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to this in your code.**

```
public void showAlertDialogButtonClicked(View view) {

    // create an alert builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Name");

    // set the custom layout
    final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    builder.setView(customLayout);

    // add a button
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // send data from the AlertDialog to the Activity
            EditText editText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            sendDialogDataToActivity(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    // create and show the alert dialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

**Use this method from**

```
  <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="showAlertDialogButtonClicked"/>
```