# Add Event Handler to ImageButton

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an Android app that has an ImageButton in it, and I need to add an event handler to it. In my attempt to do this, I have added a new function to the `.java` file that Android Studio creates when you make new project that looks like this:

```
public void tapImageButton(ImageButton myImgBtn) {
      // Code that does stuff will come later on.
}
```

After doing this, trying to set the `onClick` proerty does not show the function, and trying to enter it manually causes the app to crash when I test it.

[image: 'tapImageButton' Function Missing]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812744/how-to-set-an-onclick-listener-for-an-imagebutton-in-an-alertdialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have View as a parameter of method that you wish to call, while bind click event through layout file.

Try this:

```
public void tapImageButton(View view) {
      // Code that does stuff will come later on.
    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In xml:

```
...
android:onClick="tapImageButton"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with android studio but when i tried making a button and having it do something on click i first added the android:onClick = "some_method_name" to the XML that makes the design of the app. I first added the name in the onClick and then i clicked on the name. When the little light bulb icon shows up the arrow next to it give the option of creating a method with that method name that you just wrote. once you create it then you add the code of whatever you want to happen when you click. Hope it works.

For Example, This is the XML:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:text="@string/play"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="#0099FF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:onClick="startGame" />
```

This is the Java:

```
public void startGame(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am using an `ImageButton`, not a regular `Button`. It seems that the Java however, is identical for both `Button`s and `ImageButton`s.